# AfterUpdate combobox find and replace

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to use AfterUpdate on a combo box to have it find a record from table "Userdata" where field "Recall_position" equals "1" and replace it with "0".

Then find the record selected in the combobox (that it was updated to) and in "Userdata" under "Recall_position"  put the number "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Private Sub cmbTest_AfterUpdate()

    CurrentDb.Execute "update Userdata set Recall_position = 0 where Recall_position = 1"
    CurrentDb.Execute "update Userdata set Recall_position = 1 where ID = " & Me.cmbTest.Column(0)

End Sub
```

The first query updates all records with `Recall_position = 1` to `Recall_position = 0`.

The second query updates the record with the ID in the first column of the selected item in the combo box to `Recall_position = 1`.
*(I assumed that it's a numeric value and that the column in the table is called `ID`)*

Comment: Could be difficult if an update has occurred. You will get an error that another user has updated the record.

Answer (score 0):

So using that code I have

```
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Userdata SET Recall_position = 0 WHERE Recall_position = 10"
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Userdata SET Recall_position = 10 WHERE Lastname = '" & Me.Combo1.Column(1)  & "'"
End Sub
```

Which does clear out the 10 and updates the right row to
10 as well. However, it is also updating a second row with a random number in the Lastname

Comment: Found what it's doing but not what's causing it. When I select a new name in the box it does everything it's suppose to do. However, it's also taking the last name of the first selection in the combo box and changing it to the row count of the name selected. So if I choose the last name of Michaels and it's the 23rd item on the list, it changes the last name of the first item to 23.

Comment: Can you show us the generated SQL? *(especially the second query)*

Comment: I was able to find the problem. My table had a huge gap in ID #. I reset the ID to start back at one with no gaps and it fixed the problem.